# can I reuse zlib's z_stream for several operations?

Tags: c++, c, zlib

I am currently playing with `zlib`.

Usual example is more or less as follows (C/C++ pseudo code)

```
z_stream zs;
memset(&zs, 0, sizeof(zs));

if (deflateInit(&zs, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION) != Z_OK)
    return false;

zs.next_in  = input_data;
zs.avail_in = input_size;

zs.next_out  = output_data;
zs.avail_out = output_size;

int result = deflate(&zs, Z_FINISH);

deflateEnd(&zs);

return result == Z_STREAM_END ? true : false;
```

Using valgrind I see deflateInit and memset are not entirely "free" operations, but takes considerable time.

My question is, can I reuse `z_stream` and `deflateInit`?
e.g. can I deflate more than once by just updating the buffers?

Comment: Why not give it a test for yourself?

Comment: if I test and it does work by some miracle, it still does not mean it is correct. It could "add" the data to previous "part" or something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can use `deflateReset()` to have the same effect as `deflateEnd()` followed by `deflateInit()`, but entirely avoiding the costly de- and re-allocations.

Comment: I was hoping you to see the question :) LPs answer add some information for automatical call to deflateEnd. is deflateReset safe after this point? Is situation with InflateReset same?

Comment: There is no automatic call of `deflateEnd()`. You cannot call `deflateReset()` after a `deflateEnd()`. Yes, `inflateReset()` is the corresponding call for inflate.

Comment: Just to mention, there are 33% increase in my deflate function when I reset the structure.

Comment: 33% increase of what?

Comment: deflate performs 33 % faster with reset compared with deflate with init / end. Probably I was too much exited for the result and skip  some words.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [the man](http://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html)

> [...]The first thing we do is to initialize the zlib state for compression using deflateInit(). **This must be done before the first use of deflate()**. [..]

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

The key words is the ***before the first use***. You can call it once as far as next deflations use same configuration.

Moreover

> [...]If there is an error in reading from the input file, the process is aborted with deflateEnd() being called to free the allocated zlib state before returning the error. We wouldn't want a memory leak, now would we? **deflateEnd() can be called at any time after the state has been initialized. Once that's done, deflateInit() (or deflateInit2()) would have to be called to start a new compression process.**[...]

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

Comment: Correct. By looking at the zlib code, it can be seen that the z_stream is finalized on error, on succesfull processing the structure can be re-used.

Comment: thanks. for some reason i dont have man page for it and i did not found it on their website.

Comment: I probably need deflateReset